# Flow: string of specific stucture

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Is it possible to declare a `type` using Flow which is a `string` type of a given structure?

Example structure that I would like to match:

```
const id1 = '123a123456'
const id2 = '111b222222'
const id3 = '333c333333'
```

So basically 3 digits, then a number and next would be 6 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this in Flow. In theory, you can define the complete set manually but this isn't practically possible because there are millions (billions?) of these strings. Instead, you should write a function that does this, and Flow can typecheck the function inputs/outputs.